# Reactivate frame instead of open a new one

Tags: java, swing

Hi
I've got a MainWindow with a JTable, which is a list of Stuff. If you doubleclick on one of them, there is a detailView which open a new Frame (in a new window). Now if one detailView is already open, how can I reactivate it instead of open a new one?
Can one somehow get an Array of visible frames in Java?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a Controller class, which has all the detailViews in a Hashmap with key s. The controller has an method show(Stuff s) and if s is already in the list I do an detailView.toFront() and otherwise I create a new detailView an insert it into the Hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use `frame.setVisible(true);` the frame gets focus

---

To indicate number of opened frames, either you:

1) If you have an array of your frames in your MainWindow, then you can do this

```
getOpenedFrames() {
  int openedFrames = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<arraOfFrames.length; i++) {
    JFrame frame = arrayOfFrames[i];
    if(frame.isVisible) openedFrames++;
  }
  return openedFrames;
}
```

**OR**

2) If you don't have an array of the frames, then use a flag int to keep track of number of opened frames:

```
int openedFrames = 0;
```

every time a new frame is opened, increment openedFrames by 1, everytime a frame is closed decrement openedFrames by 1

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `CardLayout` in `detailView`, put a child panel for each `Stuff`. And then switch between children panels. The advantage is that the size of `detailView` won't change when switching panels for `Stuff`. But you will create unnecessary panels for all the Stuff.

Another way is to extend `JFrame` with some method `showStuff(Stuff s)` (or make a class which contains an instance of `JFrame` inside and provides some basic methods: `show`, `close`, `showStuff`) which clears the content of the frame and shows the new stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the "detail" window should not be a JFrame, it should be a (modal?) dialog.

I can't tell from your question if you want one detail dialog for each row in the table or one dialog for the entire table.

If you want one dialog for the table then the solution is easy, just use a modal dialog, then the user will be forced to close the detail dialog before opening another one.

If you want multiple dialogs, then use a HashMap to keep track of the open dialogs. Maybe use the row number as the key and then add the dialog as the value. You then add a WindowListener to the dialog. Every time the dialog is opened/closed you update the HashMap.